# Azure DevOps and Outlook Integration

Tags: outlook, office365, azure-devops

Looking for information on how to integrate VSTS to Office365: Outlook.  Essentially looking for a method whereby a team member that does a great amount of fix-it tickets can drop them into the Azure DevOps Project from Outlook as many of those tickets get passed to her from users through email.

A right click >> add new task from Outlook to Azure DevOps would be ideal.

Comment: You can probably get pretty close through Microsoft Flow. Use the Tagged email trigger from (https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/67477f30373611e7870df906aa521b7a/create-planner-tasks-for-flagged-emails-in-office-365/) and the create work item task from https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/e258ca20d34611e6a21125f44639ee06/when-a-build-fails-in-vsts-create-a-new-bug/

Comment: That way you can use a specific tag to send them onwards to VSTS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in feature, but you can work miracles with Microsoft Flow, basically, the If This Then That from Microsoft. it comes with built-in tasks to trigger on Outlook/Office 365. Moving an email to a specific folder or tagging it with a specific tag would be enough for Flow to trigger a rule.

[This template rule](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/67477f30373611e7870df906aa521b7a/create-planner-tasks-for-flagged-emails-in-office-365/) uses the "When an email is tagged" and this template rule creates a [Bug work item based on a trigger](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/e258ca20d34611e6a21125f44639ee06/when-a-build-fails-in-vsts-create-a-new-bug/). Combining these two should let you achieve what you're looking for.

If you want integration in the Outlook Windows client, then there are a couple of commercial options available: There are a couple of add-ins for Outlook. Team Companion, TeamLook and TFS Work Item from Outlook spring to mind.

An alternative option is to use an Azure Function which is triggered by Azure DevOps Service Hooks. Not sure if you can bind an Azure Function to an Office 365 mailbox. Flow could act as an intermediary here as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this tool called [TMO](https://gotmo.co.uk) that will enable you to create and manage work items from Outlook. It also allows you to automatically create work items in Outlook using a rule based engine called [Auto Pilot](http://gotmo.co.uk/blog/auto-pilot/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and just downloaded the TMO tool, and it works great. It does what I expected, once I figured out how to find the URL to connect to my Azure Dev Ops (ADO) server. Note: ADO is the new name for TFS or VSTS.

There's also a PowerAutomate called [Create an Azure DevOps work item when email arrives with 'Bug' in subject](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/29ef92b0630d11e6ac13ff9c624ade25/create-an-azure-devops-work-item-when-email-arrives-with-bug-in-subject/) that does just what it says. If that doesn't work for you, try modifying this one or creating your own.

Linda