# How do I connect Outlook to DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I'd like to be able to kick off a new deliverable from an email thread and have the email attached for context. I've searched for add-ins but haven't found one that works. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTS and Oulook (web) Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273219/vsts-and-oulook-web-integration)

Comment: I added more details to the answer over there.