# How to integrate an Azure Devops Calendar into Outlook

Tags: outlook, azure-devops, calendar

How can integrate an Azure DevOps Calendar into my Outlook (D365)?

Comment: Not get your latest information,does the following answers help you? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 3):

The Azure DevOps calendar is a extension: [Team Calendar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.team-calendar), and the source code is in github: https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-team-calendar

For this extension, it stores data in [Data storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/data-storage?view=azure-devops) and you can add/get/update it through REST API.

(You can check requests through Developer tool: Press F12 to open Developer tool > Network > add/update event >Check requests)

For example:

```
https://extmgmt.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/ms-devlabs/team-calendar/Data/Scopes/User/Me/Collections/%24settings/Documents

https://extmgmt.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/ms-devlabs/team-calendar/Data/Scopes/Default/Current/Collections/{team id}.{month}.{year}/Documents
```

So, you could build a outlook add-in to call these data storage REST APIs to integrate them.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It enabled me to work out a set of API calls for working with Team Calendar:
https://www.stuartellis.name/articles/ado-team-calendar/

Answer (score 2):

For this issue, if you mean the calendar in the Boards, I am afraid currently there is no out-of-box feature to achieve this.

You can integrate Azure DevOps and outlook through [Microsoft Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273219/azure-devops-and-outlook-integration), but there is currently no such flow about calendar.

In addition, in our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there is this existing suggestion: [Import Outlook Calendar Events Into Azure Calendar](https://developercommunityapi.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/idea/902895/import-outlook-calendar-events-into-azure-calendar.html). You could vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

Comment: The second link with the feature suggestion does not work, could you please update?